# Python : How to detect variables that have the same values?

Tags: python

I have like 10 variables, and I need them to have different values, if one is equal to another then redo the process from the beginning.

```
variable1 = (random.randint(1,100))
variable2 = (random.randint(1,100))
variable3 = (random.randint(1,100))
variable4 = (random.randint(1,100))
#and so on
```

I could do the stupid:  if variable1 == variable2 or variable1 == variable3 or .... etc
But I dont think that's the good way at all.
Thanks all

Comment: If you want to select 10 random numbers between 1-100 (inclusive), try using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) over a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), i.e. `random.sample(range(1, 101), 10)`.

Comment: As a basic premise: don’t ever create something like “var1”, “var2” etc. What you want is a list, or dict, or set. With a set you could keep adding random numbers into the set until it has 10 elements, the set will deduplicate values intrinsically. But as commented above, you really want a sample over a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast, brute-force way:

- Make a list of all integers 1-100
- Shuffle the list
- Pick off the first 10 numbers

Code

```
import random
toto = list(range(1,101))
random.shuffle(toto)
print(toto[:10])
```

Output

```
[80, 94, 29, 17, 26, 35, 18, 11, 58, 22]
```

Answer (score 2):

Store your variables in a list and keep generating new value until a unique value is found:

```py
variables = []
while len(variables) < 10:
    
    # Generate a new value
    new_value = random.randint(1,100)
    
    # If duplicate, don't add in list
    if new_value in variables:
        continue

    # Otherwise, add to list
    variables.append(new_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy's `np.random.choice` allows you to sample without replacement from an array, meaning that once a number has been sampled, it can't be sampled again. This would give you 10 different, randomly sampled numbers between 1 and 100:

```
import numpy as np

samples = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,101), size=10, replace=False)
```

Comment: There’s no need to bring a dependency like numpy into this…